# Breadth-first limiting on each node within a result in Gremlin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

### Background

Looking at the below image, we're facing an issue with how we want to do our limiting at a breadth-level.

The goal is to ensure that off each neighbor, we never read more than `X` edges off the current node to avoid timeouts on nodes with a large amount of edges.

### Example

We have a max-breadth limit of `X` where `X` is the number of neighbors we aggregate off a single node. We begin a BFS traversal from `0` and aggregate `3`, `1` and `2`.

Assuming our max-breath limit is `3`, the problem that can occur is that we first pull 1 and immediately begin reading *all* of 1's neighbors. As a result, we completely disregard the neighbors that could exist off of nodes `3` and `2` because `1` would fulfill the max-breadth.

### Question

How can we, in Gremlin (in a single query), say that we want an edge limit for *each* node in my list of neighbors?

In other words, I want `X` neighbors from node 3, `X` neighbors from node 1 and `X` neighbors from node 2. This idea should hold true recursively up until some depth `D`.

### Attempt

`g.V(idsList).outE().limit(50).inV().dedup.by(T.id).fold()`

The issue with the above is that we blindly limit all edges from all neighbors to `X` which can favor a single subgraph.

[image]

Comment: There was a SO post/answer with a similar question to this a while ago. I think I also have an example in Practical Gremlin. If I can't find the SO post I'll post some code as an answer.

Comment: Is this more or less what you want to do? If yes I can write up an answer more in context for your case. http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#depthlimit

Comment: Thanks Kelvin for the reference! We think we got it, but going to post a follow-up question that slightly spins off this idea.